# Can’t remove grayed out app icons on iPad 4

Tags: ipad

iPad 4 operating on iOS 10.3.3 has multiple grayed out icons that have “waiting...” under them. Have waited hours, no change. Did hard reboot, with and without WiFi, no change. Looking for suggestions on how to remove them.  Also, the App Store icon is missing. How do I restore it. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Are you able to locate App Store app by searching in Spotlight?

Comment: Touch and hold a greyed-out icon until the icons 'wiggle'. If a small X appears on the icon, touch it and the icon should disappear.